# What is this ontological position called?

Tags: philosophy

If one believes that certain 'abstract' mathematics-like concepts do exist, yet the mathematics we construct and develop as humans are only *approximations* of those real concepts, approximations shaped by our senses and perception, then what is one called?

I looked it up, and it seems like a mix of platonism and kant's philosophy?

Comment: Sounds like clear-cut platonism to me

Comment: Interesting question.

Answer (score 0):

It's called a search for noumenal waifs by Hilary Putnam in

Putnam, Hilary Models and reality. J. Symbolic Logic 45 (1980), no. 3, 464-482.